# Using linq to build a comma delimited string

Tags: linq

I need to generate a string that has a comma delimited list, but no comma after the last element.

```
var x = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
```

should yield:

```
a,b,c
```

Yes, a very simple thing to do using "normal" techniques, but I hope with linq there is a more elegant way.

```
var cols =context.Database.SqlQuery<String>("select Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = {0};", prefix + table);
```

Comment: Use String.Join to concatenate list items with coma `String.Join(",", x)`

Comment: not sure what the last line is but you need to be careful about where `prefix` and `table` come from.

Answer (score 2):

No need **Linq**, just use `String.Join`

```
String.Join(",", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` class provide `Join` method to join string array with delimiter.

Code:

```
var x = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
String.Join(",",x.ToArray());
```

documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although I strongly recommend you use the answer of `Siva Charan`, just for information here's an implementation in LinQ using [**Enumerable.Aggregate Method (IEnumerable, Func)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = x.Aggregate((c, n) => c + "," + n);
```